# Convert a string into an array of integers?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ and cannot figure this out. Simply as the question says, if I have a string (of a number), how can I convert each digit to an integer and put each into an array of integers?

Here was my attempt:

```
std::string stringNumber = "123456789"; // this number will be very large

int intNumber[stringNumber.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < stringNumber.length(); i++) 
{
    intNumber[i] = std::atoi(stringNumber[i]);
    std::cout << intNumber[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::atoi()` takes a pointer to C-string and converts the entire sequence into one integer. What you want is to convert each digit into an `int`. You can compute the `int` value of a digit `d` using `d - '0'`.

Comment: Note that in C++ you **cannot** use `int intNumber[stringNumber.length()]`! C++ does not support *variable length arrays*. If you want to use a variable sized array in C++ you'd use `std::vector<int> intNumber(stringNumber.length());`.

Comment: Also assert each input character is within ['0'..'9']. The expression 'a' - '0', for example is perfectly valid, and most-certainly *not* what you want. Validate the input string while walking it to ensure chars are, in fact, digits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a mostly prebuilt solution, I would use a vector and `std::transform`. The idea is to go through each character and add the integer form of it to the vector: ([see full sample](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48lq6z%241))

```
std::string s = "1357924680";
std::vector<int> ints;
ints.reserve(s.size()); //to save on memory reallocations, thanks Nawaz
std::transform(std::begin(s), std::end(s), std::back_inserter(ints),
    [](char c) {
        return c - '0';
    }
);
```

What this does is loop through from the beginning of the string to the end, take each character, and add the value of it minus `'0'` (`'5' - '0'` would be 5) to the end of the vector, leaving you with a vector of the integer equivalents. Best of all, it doesn't reinvent the wheel!

It also solves two problems you have:

1. It uses `std::vector` instead of a variable-length array (VLA). The latter is nonstandard, so prefer a vector if you need a runtime-sized array.
2. You use `atoi`, which is bad in itself because it returns 0 on errors, leaving no certainty of whether the result was 0 or whether there was an error. It also takes a string, not a single character. Instead this finds the distance between `'0'` and the character, which is the integer we need.

For an additional layer of security, you can use `isdigit` to check whether the character is a digit. If not, raise an error of some sort (like an exception), or deal with it however else you would. This ensures the digits in your `ints` vector will be from 0 to 9 and you won't end up with a digit of, say, 25.

Comment: Putting `ints.reserve(s.size())` before the transform would be a good idea.

Comment: @Nawaz It's more a waste of the programmer's time than anything else.  Typically (but it may not be the case with all implementations), _if_ this code has turned out to be a measurable bottle neck, creating the vector with `std::vector<int> ints( s.size() );` and using `ints.begin()`, rather than an insertion iterator, will be faster.  But it would be foolish to do either that or the reserve until you know that this is a blocking point.

Comment: And of course: 1) this only works with C++11, so isn't an option for most people, and 2) without the check for `isdigit`, the code has undefined behavior (and 3) if you just call `isdigit(c)` in the lambda, the code also has undefined  behavior.

Comment: @JamesKanze, All valid points. It can be made to work for C++03 pretty easily, by using a function instead of a lambda. Keeping C++11, the second is easy enough to fix and has a note. That said, the third one is also easy to fix, by adding an explicit return type to the lambda.

Comment: @Chris How does adding an explicit return type to the lambda help anything?  The most general solution involves writing a functional object which does the conversion, holding the necessary `std::ctype<char>`, or making the appropriate cast to the `char` before calling the C version of `isdigit`.  (`isdigit` is an exception in C, in that the global locale doesn't affect it.  In this particular case, it may actually be preferable to the C++ version.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, A lambda can only deduce the return type with well-defined behaviour if all it contains is one statement - a return statement. Anything else in the body and an explicit return type is needed (see [§ 5.1.2/4](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf)). I thought that's what you were getting at. I'm not overly sure whether that's a compiler error or undefined behaviour, though, as GCC compiles violations of that.

Comment: @chris But that has nothing to do with my third cause of undefined behavior.  If you're using the C `isdigit`, passing it a `char` variable is undefined behavior; you have to explicitly convert it to `unsigned char`.  (But you'd still only need a single return: `return isdigit( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) ) ? throw ... : ch - '0';`.  Or you could use some other convention, say returning -1 for a non-digit, or aborting.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, Oh, now I see what you mean. I should have picked up on that earlier, and yes, that would be a good one-liner for it, but it's backwards - it throws when it's a digit ;)

Answer (score 6):

You do not need atoi(). Use `intNumber[i] = stringNumber[i] - '0';`

Comment: @AaronAAA: The "-" operator on `char` type returns a distance between characters. Since Distance from char '3' to the char '0' is 3 it is common trick to use it to convert char to integer.

Comment: @AaronAAA, It takes the current character, which could be `'4'`, `'1'`, `'8'`, etc., and subtracts `'0'`. Since the digits are guaranteed to have continuous character codes, it will give the integer value of what the character is displayed as.